# Какое предложение связано с предыдущим при помощи личного местоимения и контекстных синонимов?

Tags: синтаксис, синонимы, егэ

Среди предложений 9–14 найдите такое (-ие), которое (-ые) связано (-ы)
с предыдущим при помощи личного местоимения и контекстных синонимов.

> (9) Молодой ещё и глупый.
>   (10) Почитай, ему ещё и двух месяцев нет.
>   (11) Так его приучать надо, воспитывать!
>   (12) Возвращаясь из гимназии, дядюшка зашёл в лавку и купил
>   мышеловку.
>   (13) За обедом он нацепил на крючок кусочек котлеты и
>   поставил западню под диван.
>   (14) Ровно в шесть часов вечера под диваном
>   вдруг раздалось «хлоп!».

Comment: Здесь не выполняют домашние задания. Дайте свой вариант - поможем.

Comment: Видимо, не столько д/з, сколько подготовка к ЕГЭ, можно и помочь найти контекстные синонимы, это не всегда легко

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, здесь два ответа: 10 (молодой=двух месяцев нет) и 13(мышеловка=западня).

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Смущает предложение 10:контекстные синонимы есть,есть личное местоимение. Но в 9 предложении нет предмета,для замены этим местоимением. Как вы думаете?

Comment: Ну и что? 9 предложение неполное, но ведь деятель-субъект имеется, хоть и пропущен, на него и указывает личное местоимение.

Comment: 10 предложение не неполное,а односоставное безличное. Оно было бы неполным,если бы в 9 было подлежащее.

Comment: Так я и говорю не о 10, оно-то безличное, но указание на субъект  речи есть - ему. А девятое - неполное диалогическое, это парцеллированная конструкция. О ком речь - в предыдущем предложении. Это допустимо. Посмотрите в текст задания - там нужно найти  "связанные с предыдущим" или "связанные с предыдущими"? Бывает и так, что не с одним предложением, а с несколькими.

Comment: Нет в тексте  "связанные с предыдущИМИ"?Пришли ответы. Ответ -13. Но вы мне очень помогли разобраться. Спасибо вам огромное!